# Нет перевода функции "Рекомендовать удаление" в очереди проверок "Сообщение низкого качества"

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

Нет перевода функции "Рекомендовать удаление" в очереди проверок "Сообщение низкого качества".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Предлагаю перевод `Рекомендовать удаление`. Во-первых, по-моему, именно эта фраза отображается в дальнейшем, если зайти в историю действий на вопросе, во-вторых, это дословный и наиболее точный перевод данной фразы.

P.S. На телефоне тоже не переводено. Хотя возможно, это не важно и используется jbly перевод.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перевод добавлен:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/15981

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.3.9.38746

Comment: Сборки? А как часто их обновляют?

Comment: @МаксимФисман на буднях обычно несколько раз в день, но не всегда. На выходных - практически никогда. Номер сборки указан в подвале сайта.

Comment: Ого! Так часто! По несколько раз в день?!

Comment: @МаксимФисман welcome to the world of continuous delivery!